# Calculate CPU usage for an application

Tags: android

I need to calculate the cpu usage of a perticular process in android device. I have tried to find it out using top command.
Problem is that it is completely different from the android assistant which is showing cpu usage in RTCPU percentange.
I dont know what is RTCPU. Can anyone explain me ?

I also want to know that CPU usage I have found using top command is correct or not...

Comment: Not sure it will help, but take a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467579/how-to-get-cpu-usage-statistics-on-android

Comment: "proc/stat" i have tried but it is giving total cpu usage not cpu usage for a perticular process. I have used top but dont know that cpu usage I have found is correct or not.  Thanks for your valuable help.. I will try other things too written in link that you have forwarded me..

Answer (score 1):

I also used top to get the CPU usage of my application.  You need to know the PID of the application, but after that you can query it from the results of Top.  See my answer here.

[Retrieve CPU with Top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/how-do-i-get-the-total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat/36462336#36462336)