# CPU load for C process with respect to core(s)

Tags: c, linux

I am about to find out how a specific process, in C, loads the CPU over a certain time frame.
The process may switch processor core during runtime, therefore
I need to handle that too. The CPU is an ARM processor.

I have looked at different ways to get the load, from standard top,
perf and also to calculate the load through the statistics given in the 
*/proc/[pid]/stat*-file.

My thoughts is to have a program that read the */proc/[pid]/stat*-file as suggested in the thread:
"[How to calculate the CPU usage of a process by PID in Linux from C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420426/calculating-cpu-usage-of-a-process-in-linux)" and calculate the load accordingly.
But how would I treat core switching? I need to notice it and adjust the load calculation.

How would you recommend me to achieve this?

**Update:** How can I see which core the process runs in and by that examine if it has switched core since the last chack assuming I poll the process figures/statistics at least twice?

Comment: possible duplicate of [total cpu usage of an application from /proc/pid/stat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat)

Comment: @Jahaja That post was good but it lacks the handling of when the process is executed first on core A and after a while on core B?

Comment: Which cpu core the process scheduler happens to put the process shouldn't affect the accounting of the amount of cpu time the process has received.

Comment: Alright, you are right about that @Jahaja.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `perf` tool can tell you the amount of `cpu-migrations` your process has made. That is, how many times the process has switched cpu. It won't tell you *which* cpu cores though.