# C Program to get CPU usage for a PID and all its children

Tags: c, linux, profiling

I have a C program that parses the /proc//stat directory to calculate the average CPU utilization over a period of 5 seconds:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ITERATIONS 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf( "usage: %s <PID>\n", argv[0] );
        return(-1);
    }

    long double a[4], b[4];
    long double pidTime = 0.0;
    long int clk;
    int i;
    FILE *fp;
    char stat[1024];

    clk = sysconf(_SC_CLK_TCK);

    if (clk == -1) {
        printf("Could not determine clock ticks per second");
        return(-1);
    }

    char *pidPath = malloc(strlen("/proc/stat/")+strlen(argv[1])+1);
    if (pidPath == NULL) {
        printf("Could not allocate memory for str\n");
        return(-1);
    } else {
        strcpy(pidPath, "/proc/");
        strcat(pidPath, argv[1]);
        strcat(pidPath, "/stat");
    }

    for(i = 0; i < ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
        fp = fopen(pidPath,"r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            perror(pidPath);
            return(-1);
        } else {
            fgets(stat, sizeof(stat), fp);
            sscanf(stat,"%*d %*s %*c %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*u %*lu %*lu %*lu %*lu %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf %*ld %*ld %*ld %*ld %*llu",&a[0],&a[1],&a[2],&a[3]);
            fclose(fp);
            sleep(1);
        }

        fp = fopen(pidPath,"r");
        if (fp == NULL) {
            perror(pidPath);
            return(-1);
        } else {
            fgets(stat, sizeof(stat), fp);
           sscanf(stat,"%*d %*s %*c %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*u %*lu %*lu %*lu %*lu %Lf %Lf %Lf %Lf %*ld %*ld %*ld %*ld %*llu",&b[0],&b[1],&b[2],&b[3]);
            fclose(fp);
        }

        pidTime += (((b[0]+b[1]+b[2]+b[3]) - (a[0]+a[1]+a[2]+a[3])));
    }

    pidTime = (pidTime / (clk * ITERATIONS));
    printf("pidCPU=%Lf\n", pidTime);
    printf("%ld", clk);
    free(pidPath);
    return(0);
}
```

From what I understand the relevant fields in stat are:

- int           utime;                    /** user mode jiffies **/
- int           stime;                    /** kernel mode jiffies **/
- int       cutime;                   /** user mode jiffies with childs **/
- int           cstime;                   /** kernel mode jiffies with childs **/

For a single process, this works great, but when I have a process that forks, or is multithreaded, this breaks down. Do the cutime and cstime counters only work when the parent is waiting for the child processes? How can I calculate the total usage of the process tree rooted at PID?

Comment: Why not output your errors on `stderr` ?

Comment: @Ascam I should, I think I was just being lazy at this point. You're right though.

Comment: Anyway, just following logic, since you're tracking a PID, you'll only be given infos about **this** PID. Each child process being a... **process**, you refer to them by their own ID.

My final point is: yes, it seems normal that you're getting only some `wait` activity watching parents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the parent needs to wait for the CPU time of the children to be added in (see manual entry for `getrusage` [link](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getrusage)). Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16726779/how-do-i-get-the-total-cpu-usage-of-an-application-from-proc-pid-stat) for more details.

Comment: So is there a way to get the process tree from /proc? If so, I could potentially make this a recursive solution

Comment: On some kernels, you may be able to get the children from `/proc/**pid**/task/**taskid**/children` file [see link](https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/12/28/59). Otherwise, you can do reverse lookup from the parent pid. The parent pid is listed in `/proc/*pid*/status` on line `PPid`. You can try from a shell with: `fgrep PPid /proc/[0-9]*/status 2>/dev/null | fgrep $$ | cut -d/ -f3` which should list subprocesses of your shell (`$$`). Note that the grep/cut will itself show up in this list, but these processes will be gone by the time your prompt returns.