# Get CPU usage of a device running Android 8 Oreo

Tags: android, system-calls, android-permissions, android-8.0-oreo

I'm really confused. I have just noticed that starting from Android 8 all system calls like /proc/stat will be disabled. Ok, but what is work around to get CPU Usage in Android 8? No system calls at all. Is there some API that I'm not familiar with?

I really hope that there is solution which I can't see now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, all of /proc/stat has been disabled for non-System apps, as a side-channel.

More information, with an official response from Google here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37140047

Comment: Thanks for info. It seems that root users will be more and more with each Android version ;)

Comment: seriously @Google, you just keep giving me more reasons to *not* upgrade.

Comment: @KamenStoykov How do you regain access through root? If you could post some code that would be great.

Comment: Process p = Runtime.getRunime().exec("su"). If user gives you access to SU, then connec to steams (p.getOutputstream(), p.getInputStream()) and start executing commands as you are in shell. You can'n make your main application process to run as root. The target device must have root libraries installed.

Comment: @KamenStoykov So basically try reading the same file we were before, but through adb shell commands once su is granted?

Comment: @Flyview exactly