# How to convert the clock ticks to milliseconds?

Tags: c, linux

I want to retrieve the amount of time in milliseconds that a process has spent taking up CPU time since the process was started.

I can found in the `/proc/<pid>/stat` the fields:

- `#14` `utime` - CPU time spent in user code, measured in *clock ticks*
- `#15` `stime` - CPU time spent in kernel code, measured in *clock ticks*

I think the time I want is:

```
mytime = utime + stime
```

Am I right?

And How to convert the `utime` and `stime` from clock ticks to milliseconds ?

Comment: If you specify the speed of your processor clock you would be able to work out the conversion to milliseconds!

Comment: Are you trying to get a measure in wall clock time? Because I think this `/proc` technique will be inaccurate for SMP?

Comment: Much of Linux is open-source, meaning its implementation (code) is freely available. That includes not only the Linux kernel, but also much user-space programs and command-line utilities. For example [the `time` command](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html). If you can find the source to it then you can see how they do to measure time.

Comment: Or much more simply, just use [the `getrusage` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html).

Comment: The length of a clock tick in seconds is obtained from the CPU frequency. Apply elementary school physics: `t = 1 / f`. Then simply multiply that time with the number of ticks.

Comment: @Lundin How to find the cpu frequency ?

Comment: @Lundin. what I find is `time_ms = time_tick/(CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000)`. Is it correct ?

Comment: @MOHAMED  `CLOCKS_PER_SEC/1000` may be integer division and be too inaccurate.  Try `time_ms = time_tick*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;`  Please post the type of `time_ms` for a good  answer.

Comment: @chux time_ms is time in milliseconds and it's unsigned int

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/16726779/2410359