# Do I still need to set maxmemory if I put a memory limit on the container for Redis server?

Tags: docker, redis

I want to configure Redis as an LRU cache.  I'd like to avoid repeating myself for the memory limits.  If I do

```
command: redis-server --maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru 
deploy:
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 1.5G
```

would it be enough or do I really need to put in something like this (I used a slightly lower size for the OS etc)

```
command: redis-server --maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru --maxmemory 1.4G
deploy:
  resources:
    limits:
      memory: 1.5G
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checking the `redis-cli` `info memory` it shows the total memory to be the full system size, so likely without maxmemory it will use that value.

However, using [getting the memory limit from inside the container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65551215/get-docker-cpu-memory-limit-inside-container) and a bit of `bash` arithmetic, you can create a command that will do the work so the operations only need to tweak one number rather than muck around with the `command`.  And combining with [a proper HEALTHCHECK for Redis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67904609/how-do-you-perform-a-healthcheck-in-the-redis-docker-image/70706628#70706628)

```yaml
services:
 cache:
    image: redis:6
    command:
      - bash
      - -c
      - redis-server --appendonly yes --maxmemory $$(( $$( cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes 2>/dev/null || cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory.max ) - 100000000)) --maxmemory-policy volatile-lru
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "redis-cli", "--raw", "incr", "ping" ]
    networks:
      - default
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 512M
```

This will set the maxmemory to the one defined in the compose file minus 100MB for the overhead.

The two `cat`s in the middle try both [CGroupV2 and CGroup V1 locatons for determining the memory limit](https://github.com/dask/distributed/issues/6894).