# Getting memory usage of process from .Net Core app on Linux machine

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, operating-system, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to get the total memory usage of current process from the .netcore application.

`System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().PagedMemorySize64` works fine on windows but it returns zero on Linux machine. I also tried `System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter package` to get the value but it throws platform is not supported exception.

I'm using .netcore 3.1 as framework.

Comment: If you have the possibility to upgrade to .NET 5.0, then there's a new `GC.GetGCMemoryInfo()` method that gets a lot of interesting data about the current memory usage. But sadly, it's really .NET 5 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By following the answer to [getting CPU and memory usage of a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248144/getting-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-a-docker-container-from-within-the-dockerized-ap). I simply read the file at the location `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes` and parsed it into and int variable.