# Read CPU usage for multi core cpu

Tags: android, cpu-usage

I been trying to read cpu usage in my application using the @szcoder answer to [How to get Memory usage and CPU usage in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5560634/777593) here at SOF.

His solution used to work on my Samsung Galaxy S2 (dual-core cpu), but its not working on my HTC One M7 which is quad core.

Most of the readings (Value from @szcoder's method*100 i.e percentage cpu usage) are either negative, some less than 10% and few are more than 100%.

In a comment to this answer [Dave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118234/how-to-get-memory-usage-and-cpu-usage-in-android#comment25095165_5560634) suggests that we should use multiple readings for accurate value.

Can some one please suggest a possible solution to this problem?

**EDIT :**

I also tried to use [Fabian Knapp's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10269661/777593) solution which uses `top -n 1` command to determine the CPU usage  but in my testing parsing `/proc/stat` is much faster than `top -n 1` (0.3xx seconds comapred to 3.xx seconds) so in case some one suggests it, I won't be using the top command because of time consumption.

Answer (score 1):

If the top command gives you the correct value, then I suggest you look at Android's [source code for top](https://github.com/android/platform_system_core/blob/master/toolbox/top.c) and pull out the bit you need for CPU, which takes less time than a second. I can say this works because I did it once.

Comment: Thanks for the information but can you share java code? because `top.c` is written in c and I am not very good with `c language`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote the code working for the Man, so I can't share. But look at the read_stat() function in that link, which does what you want; it's short and not incomprehensible.